# Is it possible to do a memory efficient Group By for a Sum in Linq?

Tags: linq-to-objects

If I'm using Linq To Objects on a long array of objects from a CSV file like:

```
Name, NumApples
"Fred", 1
"Fred", 2
"Jane", 2
"Pete", 1
"Fred", 1
"Bob", 3
"Jane", 2
```

and I'd like to calculate

```
var query = from p in myfile
            group p.NumApples by p.Name into grouped
            select new 
            {
                Name = grouped.Key,
                TotalApples = grouped.Sum()
            };
```

then my understanding is that the group by operation will create a `Dictionary<string, List<int>>` and that the `Sum()` values will only be calculated only after the entire file is read.

Is there any way in Linq to avoid the possibly large memory use in `Dictionary<string, List<int>>` ?

---

(I realise I can do this by not using Linq, but I love using Linq!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - ignore me....

I should have just bing'ed Jon Skeet instead. Answer is similar to [Group and Count](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84468/linq-to-log-files/)

Just by asking the question, I found the answer...